# What is the practical difference between these two ways of making web connections in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib3

I have notice there are several ways to iniciate http connections for web scraping. I am not sure if some are more recent and up-to-date ways of coding, or if they are just different modules with different advantages and disadvantages. More specifically, I am trying to understand what are the differences between the following two approaches, and what would you reccomend?

**1) Using urllib3:**

```
http = PoolManager()
r = http.urlopen('GET', url, preload_content=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
```

**2) Using requests**

```
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
```

What sets these two options apart, besides the simple fact that they require importing different modules?

Comment: The `requests` module uses (and [bundles / vendorizes `urllib3`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests/packages)) under the hood - but it provides a slightly more higher level and simpler API on top of it.

Comment: Set aside the fact that requests provides a higher level API, probably with a bit less code, are there situations when it would be preferable to opt for one or the other? Or is it generally a better option to go entirely for `requests`?

Comment: My recommendation is to always use `requests`. It just makes HTTP very pleasant to deal with, and if there's something you can't do with `requests` that you can with plain `urllib3`, I haven't come across it yet. But that's just [my opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: requests vendors a bunch of libraries (including urllib3, certifi, etc) and pre-configures them for you. If you need lower-level access or just like having control over what's going on, then you can use urllib3 directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the hood, `requests` uses `urllib3` to do most of the http heavy lifting. When used properly, it should be mostly the same unless you need more advanced configuration.

Except, in your particular example they're **not** the same:

In the urllib3 example, you're re-using connections whereas in the requests example you're not re-using connections. Here's how you can tell:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.packages.urllib3.add_stderr_logger()
2016-04-29 11:43:42,086 DEBUG Added a stderr logging handler to logger: requests.packages.urllib3
>>> requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
2016-04-29 11:45:59,043 INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
2016-04-29 11:45:59,158 DEBUG "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
>>> requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
2016-04-29 11:45:59,815 INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
2016-04-29 11:45:59,925 DEBUG "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

To start re-using connections like in a urllib3 PoolManager, you need to make a requests *session*.

```
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> session.get('https://www.google.com/')
2016-04-29 11:46:49,649 INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
2016-04-29 11:46:49,771 DEBUG "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
>>> session.get('https://www.google.com/')
2016-04-29 11:46:50,548 DEBUG "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

*Now* it's equivalent to what you were doing with `http = PoolManager()`. One more note: urllib3 is a lower-level more explicit library, so you explicitly create a pool and you'll explicitly need to specify [your SSL certificate location](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#using-certifi-with-urllib3), for example. It's an extra line or two of more work but also a fair bit more control if that's what you're looking for.

All said and done, the comparison becomes:

**1) Using urllib3:**

```
import urllib3, certifi
http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())
html = http.request('GET', url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
```

**2) Using requests**:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
html = session.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
```