# Do we need to import the requests lib to use requests if we have already imported urllib and urllib3? - urllibx, request confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I need to use 'requests' and a function from `urllib3`. In the code
[image: code importing requests and printing dir(urllib3)]
you can see the `requests` library is being imported, but at the same time it is a module/package inside `urllib3`, which has already been imported too.

Doing some research I've found that Python comes with the `urllib` package, that comes with the `request` module. On the other hand, `requests` is a module inside `urllib3`, but it is a library on its own.

`urllib` and `urllib2` are standard Python librares, but `urllib3` is a completely separated library with a confusing name. A portion of it has been included in the standard library and `requests` depends on it, but it is not a newer version of `urllib`/`urllib2`; the library that actually wants to improve is `httplib` (ref: [Github](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1065)).

> "Under the hood, *requests* uses *urllib3* to do most of the http heavy lifting. When used properly, it should be mostly the same unless you need more advanced configuration"

(ref: [Stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937110/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-making-web-connection)):

I got to these conclusions but I'm still confused: if I have already imported `urllib`, do I still need to import `requests`? What if I had imported `urllib3`?

Also, should `requests` be imported separately, as in the depicted code, or should it be import imported from one of the mentioned libraries?

Comment: It depends on which library you are actually using.

Comment: `urllib3` is an independent project; no portions of it have been included in the standard library. `requests` is an independent project that builds on top of `urllib3`. If you are using `requests`, you need to import `requests`. How it implements its functionality should not really be of significance to you, the user of the `requests` API.

Comment: Well, I'm actually referring to either urllib or urllib3, and the pic shows also other libraries... I don't understand the comment @Daniel, am I missing something?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. Do you need to use `requests`? If not, don't worry about it. if yes, then you should import it explicitly. The fact that it is contained in another library doesn't help you directly, except to imply that many of its functions might exist in the outer library.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, so it is not possible to use `request` from the imported `urllib3` (as it is a module included in it)? Is it still necessary to import it even though it is supposed to have been already installed with `urllib3` (and maybe with `urllib`)?

Comment: @Martec: It is possible to use it, but *you don't need to or need to worry about it*. It's a different, more advanced and so more complicated API to handle HTTP requests. The `requests` project *wraps* `urllib3` to give you a simpler API.

Comment: @Martec you have it backwards. `requests` uses `urllib3`: not the other way around. So you can't use `requests` from `urllib3`: and you'd not want to do that even if it *did* use `requests`. Python is not like C/C++ where there is some translation unit and includes are more or less global, it's just not how the import statement works in Python. If you want to use *anything* in `requests`, then import `requests`. Otherwise don't. You can import it many times in multiple modules, or once in a single module, or not at all: it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Yes, I need to use `requests` (edited the question in case it wasn't clear).  I had understood (but my confusion might lie here) that when you imported a library, you imported all the modules in contained, but from your question I understand that it is not the case, that even though `requests` is listed after `dir(urllib3)`, this doesn't mean that `requests` is included??

Comment: @Martec `requests` is *not* listed from `dir(urllib3)`. Some name called `request` is, though (no s on the end). Read Martjin's answer, it's enlightening in this regard

Comment: @MattMessersmith yes, it was  enlightening, as it was yours. Don't know why you don't post them as answers, but at least  I could voted them up. Maybe I should read more on what the `dir` function does as I understood it listed the functions/methods/modules from an Agora video on request, I recently saw...

Comment: @Martec yep, you've got it right, that's what the `dir` function does. I think you're confusion might be stemming around how importing works, not `dir`.

Comment: Thank (also to @JoshFriedlander ): I'll search a little bit more about how import works...   Regarding the downvotes are they because I didn't know enough about the topic to make a question? I'd like to know it to not making more questions about related issues until I'm learned on requests and libraries... (no problem at all, just to know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `requests` module, then that's the only thing you need to import. The rest is taken care of for you by Python. That `urllib3` is used by `requests` is an *implementation detail*, unless you need to access specific objects defined by the `urllib3` library you don't need to import that into your codebase.

`requests` is **not** a module inside `urllib3`. The `urllib3` module defines a `urllib3.request` (singular!) module, which is something completely different from the `requests` package:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> import requests
>>> urllib3.request
<module 'urllib3.request' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py'>
>>> requests
<module 'requests' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>
>>> requests is urllib3.request
False
```

Note that `urllib3.request` is a module inside the `urllib3` package *namespace*. `import request` (no `s`) would not import it, as that requests a top-level name. Neither would `import somethingelse.request`, as that would be a different namespace from `urllib3`. And just because the names `requests` and `request` are similar does not mean that they are the same thing. The HTTP standard deals with the abstract concept of a *request* sent to a server and the server giving back a *response*, so names in different projects dealing with HTTP will often reflect the concepts that they represent in code.

The same applies to the names `urllib` and `urllib2`. Python, once upon a time, started with a `urllib` package that was limited, and later on a `urllib2` package was added to that extended the first and added more functionality. Python 3 consolidated the two packages and reorganised the functionality into a [series of new modules under the `urllib` namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html). The `urllib3` package is an [*independent* project](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to build a better library for the same functionality. No parts of that project are incorporated into the Python standard library.

`requests` is an project that gives you a clean, straightforward, easy to use API to make HTTP requests and handle the resulting responses. Use it for that API, don't worry about the implementation details.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I actually didn't realize it was singular in `urllib3`. Also, more than worrying about implementation it was that I also had to import the urlllib3 for a `urllib3.connection_from_url(url)` instruction that now I'm finding it is probably unneeded, and thought my code would duplicate instructions or sth...